# What is the command to display VMware version from the service console?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am trying to find the command to display the version information for VMware ESXi from the service console command line. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `vmware -v` will give you something like what you're asking for:

```
# vmware -v
VMware ESXi 4.1.0 build-260247
```